# spring.datasource.driver-class-name for snappy data

Tags: hikaricp, snappydata

Hi I want to use hikariCP with snappy data. Don't want to involve GemFire in between. How can be direct implementation possible with snappy data.

I tried com.pivotal.gemfirexd.jdbc.ClientDriver which is working, but com.pivotal.snappydata.jdbc.ClientDriver os not working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
, make your question [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for coding question which have to can be reproduced to help you.use formatting tools within Stackoverflow post form to make your post more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which version of SnappyData you are using. But, the client JDBC driver class is `io.snappydata.jdbc.ClientDriver`. See [here](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/connect_using_jdbc_driver/). You can download the driver from [here](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/releases/download/v1.0.1/snappydata-client-1.6.1.jar).

Also, not sure I follow "Don't want to involve GemFire in between". SnappyData only uses components from GemFire (for things like distributed membership, etc) and this use is completely hidden.

Comment: snappydata-store-client is not able to connect getting "Container has been closed or has moved from XXXX", But when I try with gemfirexd-client 2.0-BETA its working.

Comment: Interesting. Can you shed some more light on your client app? You are using Spring data to access ? thx.

Comment: No, just for POC purpose, I am using plain POJO.